# How to append dataframes in Pandas without staggered format

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I was able to append dataframes but as they are added, they appear at the end of the one previously appended an so on.

Each dataframe has a different header name.

Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

```
df1 = df1.append(dforiginal,sort=False, ignore_index=False)
```

What’s more, every time they are appended, their index is set back to 0.  Is it possible to append each dataframe all starting at Index=0?

The screenshots below show what I'm getting(top image) and what I'm trying to accomplish (bottom image).

Thanks.

[[image: Here's what my output looks like][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG9n1.png)

[image: This what I'm trying to achieve]

Comment: probably better to use `concat` can you show some sample data from both dataframes?

Comment: Hello - I just added a screenshot representing what I'm getting.

Comment: try `pd.concat([df,df1,df2],ignore_index=True,sort=False,axis=1)`

Answer (score 1):

If I got your point correctly you want to add rows instead of columns to your Dataframe, dont you? 
Nevertheless, you could use for example this website to get a general overview on how to use the append function: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Moreover, you can reset the index if you set the keyword `ignore_index` as `True`.

Comment: Thank you for replying and sharing this link. I added a couple of images to help me describe what I want to accomplish better.  I used Excel by selecting all the blank cells but, with a big dataframe like the one I'm building for my work, the Excel workaround displays a message saying there's not enough memory to perform the operation.